# Microsoft Azure Translation

Tags: api, azure, microsoft-translator

I am building a translator machine using microsoft translator API and HUB. I am trying to build a Japanese to English translator, so I trained the system from japanese to english. I have trained some documents into my translator system. However, i got some confusion about the MT and reference.

[image: Japanese to English Training]

My question is, why API translation from microsoft is different either with MT or Reference? 
I thought the API provided from microsoft equals to MT which will become Reference after the training? Could you give me some idea?

Answer (score 1):

The **Ref:** text that you see is part of the training/test data has been provided. The **MT** text that you see is the translation of the same text that has been produced from the trained translation model. 
This is immediately after you have trained a system.

Once you have deployed a trained system, the MT text that you see will be the result of a translate API operation.

The current API translation that you see may be different because of a differently trained model being present there.